# deploying war from spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

i'm trying to create a deployable WAR based on a spring-boot project but when i run mvn clean install i get the following exception

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'env' in value "classpath:endpoints-${env}.properties"

${env} is an VM argument -Denv=dev

What should i do?

Comment: What default value is set in your pom.xml for `env`?

Comment: @DamCx there’s no default value in pom it's a vm argument

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml you have to change:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

for:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

After that, you have to compile with: mvn clean package

In that way you can compile a war with spring-boot.
But, I don't know if you can use the -Denv parameter.